# How can I use a variable as a variable name in Perl?

Tags: perl, symbolic-references

I need to achieve the following in perl

```
printmsg(@val1, $msg1) if @val1;
printmsg(@val2, $msg2) if @val2;
printmsg(@val3, $msg3) if @val3;
printmsg(@val4, $msg4) if @val4;
printmsg(@val5, $msg5) if @val5;
printmsg(@val6, $msg6) if @val6;
```

So i wrote the following snippet

```
for(my $i=1; $i < 6; $i++ ) {
    printmsg(@val$i, $msg$i) if @val$i;
}
```

It doesn't work and breaks out with errors.

Comment: You could at least show the errors.

Answer (score 37):

[Whenever you find yourself postfixing variable names with an integer index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1829927/100754), realize that you should have used an array instead:

```
my @msgs = ('msg1', 'msg2', ..., 'msg6');
my @vals = ( [ @val1 ], [ @val2 ], ..., [ @val6 ] );
```

See also the FAQ [How can I use a variable as a variable name?](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlfaq7#How-can-I-use-a-variable-as-a-variable-name)

As the answer to the FAQ notes, if the variables are not indexed by an integer, you can use a hash table:

> By using symbolic references, you are just using the package's symbol-table hash (like `%main::`) instead of a user-defined hash. The solution is to use your own hash or a real reference instead.
>
> ```
> $USER_VARS{"fred"} = 23;
> my $varname = "fred";
> $USER_VARS{$varname}++;  # not $$varname++
> ```

You should read the entire FAQ list at least once a year.

**Update:** I purposefully left symbolic references out of my answer because they are unnecessary and likely very harmful in the context of your question. For more information, see [Why it's stupid to 'use a variable as a variable name'?](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html), [part 2](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname2.html) and [part 3](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname3.html) by [mjd](http://hop.perl.plover.com/).

Comment: Or if val doesn't map numerically, use hashes:

my %errors = ( foo => 'Uh oh!',
               bar => 'Even worse!',
             );
for my $error (keys %errors) {
  printmsg($errors{$error});
}

Answer (score 5):

You can't just string variables together like that and get a resulting variable. You COULD evaluate the expression of `$msg + i`, but it's probably better if you make msg an array and just index: `$msg[$i]`.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand, you need "eval"!

```
for(my $i=1; $i < 6; $i++ ) {
  eval 'printmsg(@val'. $i . ', $msg' . $i .') if @val' . $i;
}
```

But remember! All variable(@val1, @val2, ..., @valN) must exists! As you're not providing too much of your code I'm unavaiable to infer more about this problem. Maybe you could provide more code huh?