# In Perl, how can I read from multiple filehandles in one loop?

Tags: perl, file-io

I was wondering how I could implement this in Perl:

```
while ( not the end of the files )
    $var1 = read a line from file 1
    $var2 = read a line from file 2
    # operate on variables
end while
```

I'm not sure how to read one line at a time from two files in one `while` loop.

Answer (score 11):

Seems like you wrote your answer yourself, almost. Just check for `eof` for both file handles, like so:

```
while (not eof $fh1 and not eof $fh2) {
    my $var1 = <$fh1>;
    my $var2 = <$fh2>;
    # do stuff
}
```

More reading:

- [perldoc -f open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html)
- [perldoc -f eof](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eof.html)
- [perldoc perlopentut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html)

Comment: I wrote the pseudo code for it, however I don't know how to translate it into perl. ' while (<$in-file1> || <$in-file2>) { my $var1 = $infile1.$_; my $var2 = $infile2.$_; # do stuff }' I have no idea what to do, I literally just started using perl. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Ryan `<$infile1>` will read a line from your file, so you cannot use that as your loop condition for multiple files. `eof` "Returns 1 if the next read on FILEHANDLE will return end of file " (as quoted from the perldoc). Read the documentation, is my advice. It is quite helpful.

Comment: If you prefer, you could also use `readline $fh1` and `readline $fh2` instead, which is the name of the function that the `<$fh1>` and `<$fh2>` notation actually uses under that syntax.

Answer (score 10):

**Note:** I expanded my answer in response to @zostay and @jm666's comments.

The first step in coming up with an efficient, clear, and concise answer to this question starts with the idea that related [variables go in an aggregate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829922/concatenating-variable-names-in-c/1829927#1829927). So, the array `@fh` will contain the filehandles from which we are reading simultaneously.

Then, we can read a line from each filehandle and store them in an array using the [`<>`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readline.html) operator in conjunction with [map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html). `map` takes a transformation rule and a list, and returns another list. Hence:

```
my @lines = map scalar <$_>, @fh;
```

takes the filehandles in `@fh`, and reads a single line from each (note [scalar](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html)), and puts those lines in `@lines`. This is a `one-to-one` transformation of `@fh`.

As the documentation for `<>` indicates, `<>` returns an undefined value if the end-of-file is reached, or there is an error.

Now, one way to check if we successfully read from all files is to check if the number [defined](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html) lines is the same as the number of filehandles. [grep](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) selects elements of a list that satisfy a certain criterion. Hence

```
@fh == grep defined, my @lines = map <$_>, @fh;
```

would check if the number of filehandles in `@fh` is the same as the number of defined elements in `@lines`. However, the `@fh` appearing on both sides of this comparison can indeed be confusing, so an alternative way of checking the there are no undefined elements in `@lines` is:

```
0 == grep !defined, my @lines = map <$_>, @fh;
```

If you want to put that condition in a [while](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html) loop, you have to write:

```
while (0 == grep !defined, my @lines = map <$_>, @fh) {
```

whereas if you go with an [until](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html), you can simply write:

```
until (grep !defined, my @lines = map <$_>, @fh) {
```

This means "*until at least one of the readlines returns an undefined value, execute the body of the loop*".

Now, note that [Perl's `eof`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eof.html) is different than [C's `eof`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/feof.html). The documentation for [Perl's `eof`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eof.html) notes that:

> Practical hint: you almost never need to use `eof` in Perl, because the input operators typically return `undef` when they run out of data or encounter an error.

If you check `eof` every time through the loop, you're doubling your file IO because "*this function actually reads a character and then `ungetc` s it*."

I almost always give a self-contained runnable example with my code. Below, I did not want to rely on any specific files existing on your system, so I use the always available `DATA` and `STDIN` handles. As opposed to using the `eof` function, when you use this method, you don't have to worry about where you're reading from: All you care about is whether a readline on any one of the files returned an undefined value. It can also be used with any number of filehandles. Also, you really don't have put the filehandles in an array, but as I said, related variables belong in an aggregate, so if you find yourself typing stuff like

```
my $var1 = <$fh1>;
my $var2 = <$fh2>;
```

realize that [you should have used an array to store the filehandles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829922/concatenating-variable-names-in-c/1829927#1829927).

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;

my @fh = (\*DATA, \*STDIN);

until (grep !defined, my @lines = map scalar <$_>, @fh) {
    print for @lines;
}

__DATA__
one
two
three
```

This example script will stop asking for your input on `STDIN` when the lines in `DATA` are exhausted. If you do not have any trailing blank lines in the script, you should have to enter <del>three</del> four lines before the script terminates.

Now, if you want to know which filehandles reached the end, you'd switch to using something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;

my @fh = (\*DATA, \*STDIN);

while (1) {
    my @lines = map scalar <$_>, @fh;

    if (my @eof = grep !defined($lines[$_]), 0 .. $#fh) {
        warn "Could not read from filehandle(s) '@eof'";
        last;
    }

    print for @lines;
}

__DATA__
one
two
three
```

#### Important

The loops above are designed to stop when any one of the files is exhausted. On the other hand, you might want the loops to run until all of the files are exhausted. In that case, you'd use:

```
 while (grep defined, my @lines = map scalar <$_>, @fh) {
```

Comment: Can you explain? I have no idea what that code does.  Also I'm not reading from stdin, i'm reading from 2 files. thanks

Comment: I have been programming Perl for 12 years and this is a totally non-obvious solution to give a new Perl hacker. I had to read it carefully to understand it. The answer by TLP is much better and I understood it instantly.

Comment: This __is__ really hard to understand for an beginner. (the question is no doubt comes from a beginner). Myself needed think about a bit longer too. But, +1 for the TIMTOWTDI as an "learning-material". :)

Comment: In any way I found the code complicated, I have to admit that it was perfectly explained. Thank you - really nice. :)

Comment: An ingenious method no doubt, but I pity whoever has to maintain your scripts :)   (Even if they are well commented)

Comment: @John I am curious: What part of my solution would require any future modification (assuming it's in an appropriately named method or sub)? With the explicit naming of filehandles, and explicitly checking them for `eof`, you'd need to change the code every time the number of files changed. How does code that does not need to be modified impose a maintenance cost?

Answer (score 2):

Another easy solution without explicit `eof()` checking would go like this:

```
while (defined(my $var1 = <$fh1>) and defined(my $var2 = <$fh2>)) {
    # do stuff
}
```

This uses the fact that `<>` returns `undef` if & only if you're at the end of the file.