# perl can't use string as an array ref

Tags: perl, reference, perl-data-structures

I have 4 apps. let's call them: App1, App2, App3 and App4.

for each of these apps I have an array: for example:

```
my @App1_links = (...some data...);
my @App2_links = (...some data...);
my @App3_links = (...some data...);
my @App4_links = (...some data...);
```

Now I have a loop in my code that goes thru these 4 apps and I intend to do something like this:

```
my $link_name = $app_name . "_links";
    where $app_name will be App1, App2 etc...

and then use it as : @$link_name
```

Now this code does what I intend to do when I don't use: `use strict` but not otherwise

```
The error is: Can't use string ("App1_links") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at code.pm line 123.
```

How can I achieve this functionality using `use strict`.

Please help.

Comment: It would be nice, if you provided more meaningful snippet. Do you have arrays with these names and are trying to access them?

Comment: I thought I gave enough information. Please tell me what is ambiguous in the post and I can fix it. The names can be anything but the idea is what I want to express and get the point across to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `$link_name` as a [symbolic reference](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Symbolic-references) which is not allowed under `use strict 'refs'`.
Try using a hash instead, e.g.

```
my %map = (
    App1 => \@App1_links,
    ...
);
my $link_name = $map{$app_name};
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Let me try this out.

Answer (score 4):

As I say elsewhere, [when you find yourself adding an integer suffix to variable names, think "I should have used an array"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829922/concatenating-variable-names-in-c/1829927#1829927).

```
my @AppLinks = (
    \@App1_links,
    \@App2_links,
    \@App3_links,
    # ...
);

for my $app ( @AppLinks ) {
    for my $link ( @$app ) {
        # loop over links for each app
    }
}
```

or

```
for my $i ( 0 .. $#AppLinks ) {
    printf "App%d_links\n", $i + 1;
    for my $link ( @{ $AppLinks[$i] } ) {
        # loop over links for each app
    }
}
```

Comment: My loop is going through the 4 apps, hence my need to concatenate and get the link_name. I would have to change a lot of code to loop through the array. Any other ideas?

Comment: I do not see any valid reason to use `no strict 'refs';` here. Doing that would "solve" your problem for some value of "solve". The code above loops over all the links for all the apps.