# Using a variable name as the key name in a hash (Perl)

Tags: perl

I have this block of Perl code that I want to simplify.  It's part of a subroutine, where a series of arguments are added to values to a hash of hashes.

```
$user{$account_num}{'item0'} += $item0;
$user{$account_num}{'item1'} += $item1;
$user{$account_num}{'item2'} += $item2;
$user{$account_num}{'item3'} += $item3;
$user{$account_num}{'item4'} += $item4;
$user{$account_num}{'item5'} += $item5;
$user{$account_num}{'item6'} += $item6;
```

You can see that the variable names are the same as the key names.  I seem to remember watching a friend do this kind of thing in one line once.  Something like:

```
[looping through input arguments]:
$user{$account_num}{'variable_name'} += $variable_name;
```

Does anybody know of a way to do this?

Comment: This is a very, very bad code smell. Try using a hash of array references.

Comment: [When you find yourself adding an integer suffix to variable names, think I should have used an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829922/concatenating-variable-names-in-c). Same principle applies here. Also [Why it's stupid to `use a variable as a variable name'](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html).

Comment: An array would be fine, except these aren't my real-life variable names.  It was necessary to mask them for this example, and I probably shouldn't have made them look like an array.

Answer (score 4):

The syntax is

```
for my $i (0..6) {
   my $variable_name = "item$i";
   $user{$account_num}{$variable_name} += $$variable_name;
}
```

but it assumes `$item0` and such are package variables, and its use [goes against](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html) the fundamental principles of software development.

---

You should be using an array.

```
$user{$account_num}{'item0'} += $items[0];
$user{$account_num}{'item1'} += $items[1];
$user{$account_num}{'item2'} += $items[2];
$user{$account_num}{'item3'} += $items[3];
$user{$account_num}{'item4'} += $items[4];
$user{$account_num}{'item5'} += $items[5];
$user{$account_num}{'item6'} += $items[6];
```

which allows you to use

```
for my $i (0..$#items) {
    $user{$account_num}{"item$i"} += $items[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You're over thinking it.

I can tell because I do it all of the time:

> **Me**: If I make a device that can vibrate the socket with the right frequency, I can cause that bulb to screw and unscrew. I can then attach the device to the socket...
>
> **My Son**: Dad, why don't you just use the light switch?

If you have a bunch of items called `item1`, `item2`, `item3`, etc. Why not make this an array of items? Then you would have `$item[0]`, `$item[1]`, etc. That would greatly simplify your code:

```
for item ( @items ) {
    $user{$account_name}->[$item] += $items[item];
}
```

Maybe you were using `item1` and `item2` as stand-ins to the actual variable names. Maybe they're `$widget` and `$left_handed_smoke_shifter`. In that case, you can make it a hash of items, so you would have `$item{left_handed_smoke_shifter}` and `$item{widget}`. Then, your loop would look something like this:

```
for my $item ( keys %items ) {
    $user{$account_name}->{$item} += $items{$item};
}
```

Simple, easy to understand and maintain.

However, if you really, truly insist that you need to be able to use variable names the way you insist, use `eval`:

```
$user{$account_name}->{$varible_name} = eval '$' . "$variable_name";
```

I just sell lengths of ropes that are long enough for someone to hang themselves with it. What they actually do with it is none of my business.

Comment: Yes, the variable names were indeed stand-ins. I should have been creative and chosen less array-like stand-ins.  I think I will make an array of my key names, since they are used throughout the code, and then loop through the argument inputs, in order, since they are already passed to the subroutine in an array.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm all for paring code down as much as possible, but not if it requires using unsustainable programming techniques.  So, I don't think I'll pursue EVAL.

Comment: @JohnG. Thank you for not choosing `eval`. The hash idea works though. Look at this [Perl tutorial on Object Oriented programming](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlootut.html). When you start using more complex structures than simple hashes and arrays, you should start thinking about OO programming techniques. It's really pretty simple and can save you from a ton of hurt.

Comment: You don't actually need to use eval, `$$variable_name` would also work, assuming the value of `$variable_name` was a simple string. You would need a `no strict 'refs'` before it. ( You also didn't need to put the variable in quotes `.` would have stringified it for you )

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the above code is you want to use the name of the variable as the key, which could look like this:

```
for my $item ( @items ) {
   $user{$account_num}{$item} = $item
}
```

the problem being that `$item`s value is going to be used as the key, not its name.

***Possible solutions:***

This would be greatly simplified if you also had a list of the key names:

```
my @keys = qw(item0 item1 item2 item3 item4 item5 item6);
```

Now assuming you actually have all of these items coming into your subroutine, you can easily loop

```
# 1
sub update_items {
   my @items = @_;

   for my $k ( @keys ) { 
      my $item = shift @items;          # take an item from the front
      $user{$account_num}{$k} += $item; # update
   }
}
```

OR you could use a technique called [`hash-slicing`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices) which takes a hash in list context and assigns a list of values to a list of keys:

```
# 2
sub update_items {
   my @items = @_;

   # update all keys of @keys with all values of @items
   @user{$account_num}{@keys} += @items;
}
```

Comment: Do *compound assignment operators* work with slices like that?  In my quick testing, `@h{@keys} += @values` appears merely to put a scalar context on `@values` and add that number to the last element of the slice (i.e., `$h{ $key[-1] } += scalar(@values)`).

Comment: weird, I had assumed that any assignment operator could  be used since the left side has to be calculated first anyway. I guess not though, my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example in the Perl debugger:

```
main::(-e:1):   0
  DB<1> @a=('v1', 'v2', 'v3', 'v4')

  DB<2> x @a
0  'v1'
1  'v2'
2  'v3'
3  'v4'
  DB<3> $v1=10
  DB<4> $v2=20
  DB<5> $v3=30
  DB<6> $v4=40

  DB<7> for (@a) { $hash{$_} += $$_ }

  DB<8> x %hash
0  'v4'
1  40
2  'v1'
3  10
4  'v2'
5  20
6  'v3'
7  30
  DB<10>
```

The key is `$$_`, which uses *variable indirection* to get the value of a variable whose name is contained in a variable, in this case `$_`.

Comment: +1 I forgot that you could do this.

Comment: [Why it's stupid to `use a variable as a variable name](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html)

Comment: If you think about it abstractly, variable indirection is no different from a C/C++ pointer, and the extra `$` is the de-reference operator.  Not that I would use this pattern, just answering the OP's question.

Comment: @Jim Garrison, Not so. While references are similar C and C++ pointers, and while indirection via references is perfectly fine, we're not talking about either. The topic at hand is symbolic references, something that has no peer in C and C++ since they don't have a run-time accessible symbol table.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Indent = 0;

my %user = (
    '0022334401' => [ map int(1000 * rand), 1 .. 7 ],
    '1177459393' => [ map int(1000 * rand), 1 .. 7 ],
);

my $account_id = '0022334401';

print "Before:\n", Dumper($user{$account_id}) ,"\n";

my @vals = (11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77);

# done setting up. now, update each value for $user{$account_id}
# by adding the value at the corresponding index in @vals

$user{$account_id}[$_] += $vals[$_] for 0 .. $#vals;

print "After:\n", Dumper($user{$account_id}), "\n";
```

Sample output:

```
Before:
$VAR1 = [645,553,864,165,463,455,906];
After:
$VAR1 = [656,575,897,209,518,521,983];
```

Answer (score 0):

The tidiest way is with `eval`. Like this

```
$user{$account_num}{$_} += eval "\$$_" for 'item0' .. 'item6'
```

but *remember* what others have said, that you *shouldn't be doing* this sort of thing. Refactor the code as soon as it is appropriate.