# Perl - concatenating a undefined number of strings into one string

Tags: string, perl, concatenation

I need to concatenate an undefined number of strings with Perl to create one larger string.

`$concatenated_string = $string1 . $string2 . $string3`  #..and so on for all strings provided in the file which was opened earlier in the program.

I am just a beginner, but I could not find any question on here relating to it. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: More code needed as an example. Joining the contents of a file into a string is relatively easy, but depends a bit on exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 5):

As [I have mentioned elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829922/concatenating-variable-names-in-c/1829927#1829927):

> When you find yourself adding an integer suffix to variable names, think "***I should have used an array***".

Then you can use [`join('', @strings)`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html).

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing a bit, because you don't have much example code.

But have you considered something like this:

```
open ( my $input_fh, "<", "filename" ) or die $!;
my $concatenated_string;
while ( my $line = <$input_fh> ) {
    chomp ( $line ); #if you want to remove the linefeeds.
    $concatenated_string .= $line; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

# Modern Perl is a book every one should read
use Modern::Perl '2013';

# Declaring array to store input
my @info;

# Using a loop control to store unknow number of entries
while (<STDIN>) {    # Reading an undefined number of strings from STDIN

  # Removing the \n
  chomp;

  # Stacking input value into array
  push(@info, $_);
}

# printing all entries separated by ","
say join(', ', @info);

# exit program indicating success (no problem)
exit 0;
```

OR

```
my $stream;
$stream .= $_ while <STDIN>;
print $stream;
```