# How to create multiple arrays at once in perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I'm trying to create 23 arrays without typing out `@array1`, `@array2`, and so on, and load them each with the variables from the array `@r` if the `$chrid` matches the array number (if `$chrid=1` it should be placed in `@array1`). How can I achieve this?

Here is what I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @chr;
my $input;
open ($input, "$ARGV[0]") || die;
while (<$input>) {
    my @r = split(/\t/);
    my $snps = $r[0];
    my $pval = $r[1];
    my $pmid = $r[2];
    my $chrpos = $r[3];
    my $chrid = $r[4];
    for ($chrid) {
        push (@chr, $chrid);
    }
}

close $input;
```

Comment: Use a 2D array.. see [Multi dimensional arrays in Perl](http://perlmaven.com/multi-dimensional-arrays-in-perl)

Comment: To quote Sinan Ünür [quoting himself](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28506350/176646), "When you find yourself adding an integer suffix to variable names, think **'I should have used an array'**." In this case, you want an array of arrays, as Håkon Hægland said.

Comment: Are you suggesting I create an array with 23 dimensions?

Comment: @Jack No, an array with 23 elements, where each element is a reference to another array.

Comment: Sorry I was asking that to Håkon Hægland

Comment: But can you give me a sample code please @ThisSuitIsBlackNot

Comment: @Jack Hunter McMillen already did. See the answer below.

Comment: Ok thanks for your time

Answer (score 5):

You can use an array of arrays, where each subarray is stored at a sequentially increasing index in your array of arrays. Here is what that *could* look like, but it is still unclear to me what you want data you want to store:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @chr;
open my $input_fh, '<', $ARGV[0]
   or die "Unable to open $ARGV[0] for reading: $!";
while (< $input_fh> ) {
    # you can unpack your data in a single statement
    my ($snps, $pval, $pmid, $chrpos, $chrid) = split /\t/;

    # unclear what you actually want to store
    push @{ $chr[$chrid] }, ( $snps, $pval, $pmid, $chrpos, $chrid );

}
close $input_fh;
```

Comment: Thanks and I would like to store a line that contains $snps, $pval, $pmid, $chrpos, and $chrid