# Dynamic array creation in perl

Tags: arrays, perl, foreach

I have read this post and saw that there are various ways to create a dynamic naming of arrays in perl.
`http://en.allexperts.com/q/Perl-CGI-1045/dynamic-naming-array-1.htm`

as per the link, the code will create dynamic arrays like these:

```
@yearsSoFar2004, 
@yearsSoFar2005,                                                                               
@yearsSoFar2006 etc.
```

My requirement is as follows. I want to create a dynamic array like this:

```
my @a0=();
my @a1=();
my @a2=();
my @a3=();
```

I currently have it static in my code but i want to make it dynamic. Here is the static code below. Please help me guys. I am a newbie to PERL

```
my @a=();
my @b=();
my @c=();
my @d=();
```

Comment: The name of the language is "Perl", not "PERL" or "perl" (though the latter can be used to refer to the executable).

Comment: @ikegami- i just saw ur profile. Soreadytohelp..... it said... you should think of correcting that.. you can write as follows. Onlyreadytofindfaults

Comment: How is showing you the correct spelling of the language you are trying to learn not helpful?!

Comment: @ikegami- the spelling is right. Perl, PERL and perl are all spelt the same way. I would rather need your help in finding me a solution for this. If at all there is a solution. Please help if you are soreadytohelp

Comment: [No](https://www.perl.org/about/style-guide.html). It's not an abbreviation.

Comment: @ikegami- okay, Perl... got it. :) will keep a note of it from now on...

Answer (score 3):

Three problems with your request:

1. `my` declares a lexical variable at compile-time, so asking to pass a name to `my` at run-time makes no sense.
2. Symbolic references can't be used to access lexical variables.
3. [It's a stupid thing to do](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html).

Comment: @ikegami- Agreed, its stupid thing to do this way. but can i have a solution for this please. The code has been developed already and i need to make it dynamic now on that same code.

Comment: I gave you two reasons why it's impossible. I'm not sure what you hope to gain by pleading.

Comment: @ikegami- thanks for the ultimatum. i was just not sure if i could make it dynamic or not. will have to find other way then.

Comment: If you tell us what you are actually trying to accomplish, we can help you with that.

Answer (score 2):

> My requirement is as follows. I want to create a dynamic array like this:
>
> ```
> my @a0=();
> my @a1=();
> my @a2=();
> my @a3=();
> ```

As I have said before, "[When you find yourself adding an integer suffix to variable names, think I should have used an array.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1829927/100754)"

So, instead, use

```
my @data = (
    [ ... ],
    [ ... ],
    [ ... ],
);
```

If you wanted index each year's data array by the year (instead of integers 0, 1, 2, ..., n), then use a hash:

```
my %data = (
    2005 => [ ... ],
    2006 => [ ... ],
    2007 => [ ... ],
);
```

What you have now is [compounded stupidity](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html). Don't do that.