# No idea how to properly receive and use user input

Tags: c, arrays, scanf

I have the main code I want to use written out. All I need to do is get the user to input five numbers. Then once they insert the numbers I need them to be inputted into the array so that they can be calculated. I have tried to understand how to successfully get user input and use it, but have been unable to figure it out.

```
int
main (int argc, char **argv)
    {
    int number1;
    int number2;
    int number3;
    int number4;
    int number5;
    int a[5];
    printf("Enter a number\n");
    scanf ("%d, number1");
    printf("Enter a number\n");
    scanf ("%d, number2");
    printf("Enter a number\n");
    scanf ("%d, number3");
    printf("Enter a number\n");
    scanf ("%d, number4");
    printf("Enter a number\n");
    scanf ("%d, number5");
    a[0] = number1;
    a[1] = number2;
    a[2] = number3;
    a[3] = number4;
    a[4] = number5;
    int mean = (a[0] + a[1] + a[2] + a[3] + a[4]) / 5;
    int difference0 = a[0] - mean;
    int difference1 = a[1] - mean;
    int difference2 = a[2] - mean;
    int difference3 = a[3] - mean;
    int difference4 = a[4] - mean; 
    int variance = ((difference0 * difference0) + (difference1 * difference1) + (difference2 * difference2) + (difference3 * difference3) + (difference4 * difference4)) / 5;
    double sdeviation = sqrt(variance);

    printf("the mean of the array is %d\n",mean);
    printf("the variance of the array is %d\n",variance);
    printf("the standard deviation of the array is %f\n",sdeviation);
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `scanf ("%d, number1");` is that a typo?

Comment: Try `scanf (" %d", &number1);`

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you don't need the `numberN` local variables. You can define the array and read the numbers into it directly.

That said, do not repeat the same code over and over again.

Change the code like

```
#define ARRSIZE 5

int a[ARRSIZE] = {0};
for (int i = 0; i < ARRSIZE ; i++) {
  printf("Enter a number\n");
  scanf ("%d", &a[i]);
 }
```

Also, it's always a good practice to check the return value of `scanf()` function to ensure that the scanning was successful.

**Suggestion:** Always enable compiler warnings and try to resolve the warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the other answer by @Sourav, there are principles you have to learn as a programmer. One of which is, if you have to repeat any task with minor variations, you're most likely going to use a loop. Also, to quote [Sinan Ünür](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1829927/3550662)

> When you find yourself adding an integer suffix to variable names, think **I should have used an array.**

If you wish to create 5 `int` variables and you're just naming each one: number1 ... number 5, then you should just create an array to hold them all. It is a lot easier and enables you to refer to each one dynamically because of how arrays work.

```
int numbers[5]; //Now you can refer to each one by numbers[X]

...

for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    numbers[i] = a[i] - mean;
}
```

Those are just two very small modifications I would have added to your code so that it is a lot smaller and easier on the eyes. You'll learn this a lot better as you go along.

Answer (score 0):

You need **&** operator before the variable you want to assign the upcoming value. On that way, you are saying that **num1 = 4**, where for is the user's value.

- When you declare same type variables, just put then in row separated by comma. You don't need a new line for each one.It makes your code more legible
- **int argc** and **char **argv** params, are not being used in this function and instead are consuming unnecessary ram memory

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{

    int num1,num2, num3, num4, num5;

    printf("Enter #1:\n");
    scanf ("%d", &num1);
    printf("Enter #2:\n");
    scanf ("%d", &num2);
    printf("Enter #3:\n");
    scanf ("%d", &num3);
    printf("Enter #4:\n");
    scanf ("%d", &num4);
    printf("Enter #5:\n");
    scanf ("%d", &num5);

    int mean = (num1 + num2 + num3 + num4 + num5) / 5;
    int difference0 = num1 - mean;
    int difference1 = num2 - mean;
    int difference2 = num3 - mean;
    int difference3 = num4 - mean;
    int difference4 = num5 - mean;

    int variance = ((difference0 * difference0) + (difference1 * difference1) + (difference2 * difference2) + (difference3 * difference3) + (difference4 * difference4)) / 5;
    double sdeviation = sqrt(variance);

    printf("the mean of the array is %d\n",mean);
    printf("the variance of the array is %d\n",variance);
    printf("the standard deviation of the array is %f\n",sdeviation);

    return(0); 
}
```