# Parsing a file by summing up different columns of each row separated by blank line

Tags: perl

I have a file input as below;

#

```
volume stats
start_time  1
length      2
--------
ID
0x00a,1,2,3,4
0x00b,11,12,13,14
0x00c,21,22,23,24

volume stats
start_time  2
length      2
--------
ID
0x00a,31,32,33,34
0x00b,41,42,43,44
0x00c,51,52,53,54

volume stats
start_time  3
length      2
--------
ID
0x00a,61,62,63,64
0x00b,71,72,73,74
0x00c,81,82,83,84
```

#

I need output in below format;

```
1 33    36  39  42
2 123   126 129 132
3 213   216 219 222
```

#

Below is my code;

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
#use File::Find;

# Define file names and its location
my $input = $ARGV[0];

# Grab the vols stats for different intervals
open (INFILE,"$input") or die "Could not open sample.txt: $!";
my $date_time;
my $length;
my $col_1;
my $col_2;
my $col_3;
my $col_4;
foreach my $line (<INFILE>)
{

    if ($line =~ m/start/)
        {
            my @date_fields = split(/   /,$line);
            $date_time = $date_fields[1];
        }
    if ($line =~ m/length/i)
        {
            my @length_fields = split(/ /,$line);
            $length = $length_fields[1];
        }
    if ($line =~ m/0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+/)
        {
            my @volume_fields = split(/,/,$line);
            $col_1 += $volume_fields[1];
            $col_2 += $volume_fields[2];
            $col_3 += $volume_fields[3];
            $col_4 += $volume_fields[4];
            #print "$col_1\n";
        }
    if ($line =~ /^$/)
        {
            print "$date_time $col_1 $col_2 $col_3 $col_4\n";
                $col_1=0;$col_2=0;$col_3=0;$col_4=0;
        }
}
close (INFILE);
```

#

my code result is;

```
1
 33 36 39 42
2
 123 126 129 132
```

#

BAsically, for each time interval, it just sums up the columns for all the lines and displays all the columns against each time interval.

Comment: [When you find yourself adding an integer suffix to variable names, think ***I should have used an array***.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1829927/100754)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$/` is your friend here. Try setting it to `''` to enable paragraph mode (separating your data by blank lines).

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

local $/ = ''; 

while ( <> ) {
    my ( $start ) = m/start_time\s+(\d+)/;
    my ( $length ) = m/length\s+(\d+)/;
    my @row_sum; 
    for ( m/(0x.*)/g )  {
        my ( $key, @values ) = split /,/; 
        for my $index ( 0..$#values ) {
           $row_sum[$index] += $values[$index];
        }
    }
    print join ( "\t", $start, @row_sum ), "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
1       33      36      39      42
2       123     126     129     132
3       213     216     219     222
```

NB - using tab stops for output. Can use `sprintf` if you need more flexible options.

I would also suggest that instead of:

```
my $input = $ARGV[0]; 
open (my $input_fh, '<', $input) or die "Could not open $input: $!";
```

You would be better off with:

```
while ( <> ) {
```

Because `<>` is the magic filehandle in perl, that - opens files specified on command line, and reads them one at a time, and if there isn't one, reads `STDIN`. This is just like how `grep`/`sed`/`awk` do it.

So you can still run this with `scriptname.pl sample.txt` or you can do `curl http://somewebserver/sample.txt | scriptname.pl` or `scriptname.pl sample.txt anothersample.txt moresample.txt`

Also - if you want to `open` the file yourself, you're better off using lexical vars and 3 arg open:

```
open ( my $input_fh, '<', $ARGV[0] ) or die $!;
```

And you really shouldn't ever be using 'numbered' variables like `$col_1` etc. If there's numbers, then an array is almost always better.

Comment: Thanks Sobrique, it did serve my need. I wanted to ask one more query, If I have another file having entry of hex numbers in different line as below
0x00a
0x00b
Then, how do I add only those rows columns. I added if condition as if ($_ eq /^0x00a/), but it did not work.

    The final output would look like. The third line won't come as it starts     with '0x00c'.
 1       33      36      39      42
 2       123     126     129     132

Comment: Better to ask that as a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, a block begins with `start_time` and ends with a line of of whitespace. If instead end of block is always assured to be an empty line, you can change the test below.

It helps to use [arrays instead of variables with integer suffixes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1829927/100754).

When you hit the start of a new block, record the `start_time` value. When you hit a stat line, update column sums, and when you hit a line of whitespace, print the column sums, and clear them.

This way, you keep your program's memory footprint proportional to the longest line of input as apposed to the largest block of input. In this case, there isn't a huge difference, but, in real life, there can be. Your original program was reading the entire file into memory as a list of lines which would really cause your program's memory footprint to balloon when used with large input sizes.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $start_time;
my @cols;

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    if ( $line =~ /^start_time \s+ ([0-9]+)/x) {
        $start_time = $1;
    }
    elsif ( $line =~ /^0x/ ) {
        my ($id, @vals) = split /,/, $line;
        for my $i (0 .. $#vals) {
            $cols[ $i ] += $vals[ $i ];
        }
    }
    elsif ( !($line =~ /\S/) ) {
        # guard against the possibility of
        # multiple blank/whitespace lines between records
        if ( @cols ) {
            print join("\t", $start_time, @cols), "\n";
            @cols = ();
        }
    }
}

# in case there is no blank/whitespace line after last record
if ( @cols ) {
    print join("\t", $start_time, @cols), "\n";
}

__DATA__
volume stats
start_time  1
length      2
--------
ID
0x00a,1,2,3,4
0x00b,11,12,13,14
0x00c,21,22,23,24

volume stats
start_time  2
length      2
--------
ID
0x00a,31,32,33,34
0x00b,41,42,43,44
0x00c,51,52,53,54

volume stats
start_time  3
length      2
--------
ID
0x00a,61,62,63,64
0x00b,71,72,73,74
0x00c,81,82,83,84
```

Output:

```
1  33  36  39  42
2   123 126 129 132
3   213 216 219 222
```

Comment: Is there any advantage in general writing `my ($id, @vals) = split ...` instead of using something like `@vals = splice [split...], 1` to remove a useless first item, or is it just more idiomatic? Other thing, take care that the file may not have a newline at the end.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte `$id` might be useful ... if not, use `(undef, @vals)` instead of `splice` to avoid allocating memory for the first element.

Comment: `undef` obviously! I was looking for something like this but I didn't find a way to write it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code, I get warnings:

```
Use of uninitialized value $date_time in concatenation (.) or string
```

I fixed it by using `\s+` instead of `/  /`.

I also added a `print` after your loop in case the file does not end with a blank line.

Here is minimally-changed code to produce your desired output:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# Define file names and its location
my $input = $ARGV[0];

# Grab the vols stats for different intervals
open (INFILE,"$input") or die "Could not open sample.txt: $!";
my $date_time;
my $length;
my $col_1;
my $col_2;
my $col_3;
my $col_4;
foreach my $line (<INFILE>)
{
    if ($line =~ m/start/)
        {
            my @date_fields = split(/\s+/,$line);
            $date_time = $date_fields[1];
        }
    if ($line =~ m/length/i)
        {
            my @length_fields = split(/\s+/,$line);
            $length = $length_fields[1];
        }
    if ($line =~ m/0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+/)
        {
            my @volume_fields = split(/,/,$line);
            $col_1 += $volume_fields[1];
            $col_2 += $volume_fields[2];
            $col_3 += $volume_fields[3];
            $col_4 += $volume_fields[4];
        }
    if ($line =~ /^$/)
        {
            print "$date_time $col_1 $col_2 $col_3 $col_4\n";
            $col_1=0;$col_2=0;$col_3=0;$col_4=0;
        }
}
print "$date_time $col_1 $col_2 $col_3 $col_4\n";
close (INFILE);


__END__

1 33 36 39 42
2 123 126 129 132
3 213 216 219 222
```