# setting variable name with variable at the end - perl

Tags: perl

```
$id = 1;
foreach (@products) {
$productid$id = param(product$id);
++$id;
}
```

I am trying to loop through the products array and create a new variable for each item in products for a form which uses checkboxes to select products which are for sale. I tried to use $productid$id and $productid"$id" but it returned syntax errors. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Don't do that. That's exactly why arrays and hashes were invented.

Answer (score 4):

> *I am trying to loop through the products array and create a new variable for each item in products.*

While it is possible to create a new variable for each item, it's a bad idea. They have to be global, the syntax is ugly, and it's difficult to pass those variables around as a collection. Instead, ***use a hash or an array***. In this case, since your items are indexed by number and there's no gaps an array makes the most sense.

```
my @product_params;
foreach my $product (@products) {
    push @product_params, param($product);
}
```

For each `$product` in `@products`, it will add `param($product)` to `@product_params`. For example, the parameter for `$products[5]` is stored in `$product_params[5]`.

Since this is a one-to-one mapping of `@products` to its parameters, its easier and faster to do the above with a [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html). A mapping runs each element of a list through a function to create a new list. `$_` contains each element of `@products` in turn.

```
my @product_params = map { param($_) } @products;
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Variables aren't interpolated in single quotes.
2. You're resetting the $id in each iteration of the loop.

Update: Your changes invalidated both the bullets above.

```
my $id = 1;
for my $product (@products) {
    $product_id = param("product$id");
    ++$id;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, is there a way to set the end of the variabe with the value of $id? For example: $productid1 $productid2 etc

Comment: @KieranO'Connor: Why? Use an array instead.

Comment: maybe my logic is bad but I need to upload each product the user requests into a mysql table and wanted to set a variable for each product ordered.

Comment: Just `push @products, param("product$id");` and use the array.

Comment: @KieranO'Connor [When you find yourself adding an integer suffix to variable names, think "**I should have used an array**"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829922/concatenating-variable-names-in-c/1829927#1829927).

Answer (score 1):

Say you have four checkboxes named

- `product1`
- `product2`
- `product3`
- `product4`

Say `product1` and `product3` are checked.

The following will place `1` and `3` in `@selected_product_ids`:

```
my @selected_product_ids =
      map { my ($id) = /^product(\d+)\z/; defined($id) && param($_) ? $id : () }
         params();
```

If you have the list of all existing product ids in `@product_ids`, the following will do the same:

```
my @selected_product_ids =
      grep { param("product$_") }
         @product_ids;
```