# How to return a array with a given name in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I have lot of arrays saved as data for my automation , now i need have one method which will return an array with a given name .How can i do that. Kindly help .

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my @array1 = (1..4);

sub retArray {
    my $arr = shift;
    print $arr;
    ##Here i need to get the array with String which i got from args 
}

my @arrayReturned = retArray('array1');

use Data::Dumper;

print "\n";
print Dumper(\@array1);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the array in a hash:

```
my %arrays = ( 'array1' => [1..4] );

sub retArray {
    my $array_name = shift;
    return @{$arrays{$array_name}};
}
```

A list may be more appropriate, see: [How can I use a variable as a variable name in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549685/how-can-i-use-a-variable-as-a-variable-name-in-perl)

```
my @arrays;
push @arrays, \@array1;
push @arrays, \@array2;

sub retArray {
    my $array_num = shift;
    return @{$arrays[$array_num]};
}
```

Comment: Thankyou ...i will have to add all arrays to this hash in this case if i understood it right. This will be a manual effort again. I will be adding arrays with an automated program and appending new arrays to the file . Is there any other way out please ...Meanwhile i am exploring if i can use this way ...Thankyou for your help ..very kind of you ..

Comment: A list may not be an option as each array might have a lot of elements, basically i am saving XPATHS in array and returning array of elements which represent a Screen . Maintainability will reduce in that case i think

Answer (score 1):

Create a hash with the array name as a key and value an anon array ref containing the values you want.

Say something like:

```
my %map_array_ref;
$map_array_ref{'array1'} = [1,2,3];
```

Comment: Thankyou for helping me ...please read the requirement elaborated in comments in the above discussion with @RobEarl