# In Perl, how can I loop through variable names?

Tags: perl, for-loop

I have N array and i want to print 1st elements of them in single for loop

my code:

```
@arr1=qw(1..5);
@arr2=qw(6..10);
...
@arrN=qw(...);
for($i=1;$i<=$N;$i++)
{
print "$arr[$i][0]";
}
```

Comment: Which language? Also, just put then in an array and iterate that instead.

Comment: i use perl. There is a syntax whixh i am not following here, like $arr({$i})[0] or similar.

Comment: Why are you using numbered arrays like that in the first place?

Comment: Thanks all, but your reply didnt solved my question, i figured it out myself

Comment: @arr1=(1..5);
@arr2=(6..10);
for($i=1;$i<=2;$i++)
{
print "${'arr'.$i}[0]\n";
}

Answer (score 5):

When you find that you need to know the names of 0 .. N different variables. Its time to consider that you might be doing it wrong.

Arrays = list of 0 .. N values, can be sequential

Hash = list of 0 .. N named values

For your arrays, unless you actually want to be converting to strings, don't use `qw()` just use the bare `()`

See solution below, you need an array of arrays:
    #!/usr/bin/perl

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $n = 10;
my @nArrays;

#fills the nArrays list with array_refs
for my $num(0 .. $n){
  push @nArrays, [($num .. $num+5)]; 
}

#Print out the arrays, one per row, long way
for my $array (@nArrays){
  print $array->[0], "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If, contrary to all normal recommendations, you leave `use strict;` out of your script, you could use:

```
$N = 3;
@arr1 = (1..5);
@arr2 = (6..10);
@arr3 = (7..12);
@arrs = ("arr1", "arr2", "arr3");
for ($i = 0; $i < $N; $i++)
{
    print "$arrs[$i][0]\n";
}
```

Output:

```
1
6
7
```

This is absolutely not recommended, but it does work still (mainly for reasons of backwards compatibility).

With `use strict;` etc, you can use explicit references:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $N = 3;
my @arr1 = (1..5);
my @arr2 = (6..10);
my @arr3 = (7..12);
my @arrs = (\@arr1, \@arr2, \@arr3);
for (my $i = 0; $i < $N; $i++)
{
    print "$arrs[$i][0]\n";
}
```

Output:

```
1
6
7
```

On the whole, though, you would do better with a single array of arrays, perhaps like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $N = 3;
my @arr = ( [1..5], [6..10], [7..12] );
for (my $i = 0; $i < $N; $i++)
{
    print "$arr[$i][0]\n";
}
```

Output:

```
1
6
7
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have in mind is called a [symbolic reference](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html), and generally not a [good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549685/how-can-i-use-a-variable-as-a-variable-name-in-perl/1549695#1549695).

If the values of these variables belong together, there is already a data structure that is indexed by an integer: Use an array to hold them:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @arr = (
   [ 1 .. 5  ],
   [ 6 .. 10 ],
   # ...
   [ 1_000_000 .. 1_000_005 ],
);

for my $i (0 .. $#arr) {
   print $arr[$i][0], "\n";
}
```