# \shift isn't working within eval string

Tags: perl

Using `shift` within `eval` string that's inside a `sub` isn't working:

Example 1 (using `eval`):

```
grab_variable($variable1,$variable2,$variable3);
print $variable1.$variable2.$variable3; #should print: 123

sub grab_variable {
    my $number_of_parameters = @_;
    my $command1;
    my $command2;
    for (my $i = 1; $i <= $number_of_parameters; $i++) {
        $command1.= "\$RefVariable".$i." = \\shift;\n";
            #Generates string like:
                #$RefVariable1 = \shift;
                #$RefVariable2 = \shift;
                #...
    }
    eval $command1;
    for (my $i = 1; $i <= $number_of_parameters; $i++) {
        $command2.= "\$\{\$RefVariable".$i."\} = ".$i.";\n";
            #Generates string like:
                #${$RefVariable1} = 1;
                #${$RefVariable2} = 2;
                #...
    }
    eval $command2;
}
```

Example 2 (direct code):

```
grab_variable($variable1,$variable2,$variable3);
print $variable1.$variable2.$variable3; #Prints: 123

sub grab_variable {
    $RefVariable1 = \shift;
    $RefVariable2 = \shift;
    $RefVariable3 = \shift;
    ${$RefVariable1} = 1;
    ${$RefVariable2} = 2;
    ${$RefVariable3} = 3;
}
```

Example 1 is dynamic and achieves a solution to my real (not simplified) problem. How could I make `\shift` work within the `eval` code string?

Specifically, I'm trying to make a function *(subroutine)* that accepts any number of variables *(as arguments)* and get passed as references (not values) because it should modify them.

Comment: `$grab_variable($var)` is invalid syntax.

Comment: `"\$RefVariable" . $i` is a [code smell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549685/how-can-i-use-a-variable-as-a-variable-name-in-perl). Isn't there a way to do this with arrays?

Comment: Also, if you're just trying to do pass-by-reference, the contents of `@_` are already aliases to the arguments passed to the subroutine. `$ref=\shift; $$ref="foo";` is equivalent to `$_[0]="foo"`

Comment: @mob `$$ref="foo"`.  And, no, they aren't equivalent, one modifies the caller's variable and one doesn't.

Comment: @ysth - good catch. But `$$ref=...` does modify the caller's variable.

Comment: Can you explain more generally what you're trying to do? There's almost certainly a better way to do it.

Comment: @simbabque I fixed it. Thanks

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I'm trying to make a function that accepts any number of variables and get passed as references (not values) because it should modify them.

Comment: @Omar `sub modify_args { $_ = 'foo' for @_ }` is much simpler. To modify subroutine arguments, simply access `@_` directly, e.g. `$_[0] = 42;`.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Amazing. `$_[0]` acts as a **variable** *(not reference)* interpolating the variable's value in a ***calling context*** **(e.g.** `print $_[0];` prints first argument's value (*not its referencing value somewhat like* `SCALAR(0x10ef1b0)`) without the need to type `print ${$_[0]}` which doesn't work **)**. While it acts as a ***reference*** to the first argument modifying the variable's value in a modifying context **(e.g**. `$_[0] = 4;` **)**.

Comment: It's called aliasing. An alias is just another name for the same thing. `$_[0]` is an alias for the first subroutine argument. See [Alias vs Reference](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=976523) on PerlMonks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In subs, `shift` is short for `shift(@_)`.

Outside of subs, `shift` is short for `shift(@ARGV)`.

This applies in code passed to `eval EXPR` too.

Replace

```
$command1.= "\$RefVariable".$i." = \\shift;\n";
```

with

```
$command1.= "\$RefVariable".$i." = \\shift(\@_);\n";
```

---

You should always use `use strict; use warnings qw( all );`. Your code does everything you shouldn't do, and this would catch that.

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but have you considered

```
sub set_variables {
   for my $i (0..$#_) {
      $_[$i] = $i;        # Changing the elements of @_ changes them in the caller.
   }
}

set_variables(my ($var1, $var2, $var3));

say "$var1 $var2 $var3";
```

or

```
sub grab_variables { return \@_; }

my $ref_variables = grab_variables(my ($var1, $var2, $var3));

for my $i (0..$#$ref_variables) {
   $ref_variables->[$i] = $i;
}

say "$var1 $var2 $var3";
```

Comment: Yes I'm too close to understanding why `shift` doesn't work within `eval EXPR`. What does `shift` stands for within `eval EXPR`? It seems it doesn't stand for `shift(@_)` within eval.

Comment: Your code isn't in a sub, so `shift` is short for `shift(@ARGV)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Totally explained why `shift` doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Perl already does pass-by-alias to subroutines, which is even simpler than pass-by-reference. The contents of `@_` are aliases to the inputs to the subroutine; modifying `$_[$i]` modifies the i-th values passed to the sub.

```
sub grab_variables {
    for my $i (0 .. $#_) {
        $_[$i] = $i+1;
    }
}
my ($variable1,$variable2,$variable3);
grab_variable($variable1,$variable2,$variable3);
print $variable1.$variable2.$variable3;           #Prints: 123
```