# How can I reference a hash using a variable name?

Tags: perl, hash, hashref

I have a set of pre-defined hash tables and I want to reference one of those hashes using a variable name and access a key value. The following code just returns null even though the hash is populated. What am I doing wrong here, or is there a better way to achieve this?

```
my %TEXT1 = (1 => 'Hello World',);
my %TEXT2 = (1 => 'Hello Mars',);
my %TEXT3 = (1 => 'Hello Venus',);

my $hash_name = 'TEXT1';

my $hash_ref = \%$hash_name;
print ${$hash_ref}{1};  #prints nothing
```

Comment: It would help a lot if you explained what you expected `my $hash_ref = \%$hash_name` to do.

Comment: I want hash_ref to refer to a hash defined by the variable name. Edited question to clarify.

Comment: See also [Whenever you find yourself postfixing variable names with an integer index, realize that you should have used an array instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549685/how-can-i-use-a-variable-as-a-variable-name-in-perl).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a hash to contain your hashes.

```
my %texts = (
    TEXT1 => { 1 => 'Hello world', },
    TEXT2 => { 1 => 'Hello Mars', },
    TEXT3 => { 1 => 'Hello Venus', },
)

my $hash_name = 'TEXT1';

print $texts{$hash_name}{1}, "\n";
```

Answer (score 5):

The code you have works just fine<sup>*</sup>

```
%TEXT = (1 => abc, 42 => def);
$name = 'TEXT';
print ref($name);         #  ""
no strict 'refs';
print ${$name}{1};        #  "abc"
print $name->{42}         #  "def"
$ref = \%$name;
print ref($ref);          #  "HASH"
print $ref->{1};          #  "abc"
print ${$ref}{42};        #  "def"
```

The main thing that you are doing wrong is [making your code an unmaintainable mess](https://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html), and that is why this sort of thing is not allowed under `use strict 'refs'`.

* - unless you are running under `use strict 'refs'`, which you should be

Comment: I am using `strict`. Is there a way of doing this without dereferencing?

Answer (score 0):

The following code is assignment to a scalar, not to a hash:

```
my $hash_name = 'TEXT';
```

The following code is assignment to a hash:

```
my %hash = ( alpha => 'beta', gamma => 'delta' );
```

To print the value of a single element from the hash, you say:

```
print $hash{alpha}, "\n";
```

You can take a reference to that hash and assign that to a variable:

```
my $hashref = \%hash;
```

And from that you can print a single element from that hashref:

```
print $hashref->{alpha}, "\n";
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. I want to reference the hash with the name taken from a scalar variable. In other words, I have a set of hash tables already defined and I need to access values from any one of those tables depending on user input. So the scalar will define the name of the hash, then I want to define the hash_ref using that name. Sorry if this wasn't clear.