# How to use element value in an array to define a set of hashes in PERL?

Tags: perl

My question is shown in the title.

I have raw data which may have various elements. I want to define hash whose name is based on the raw elements. Here is an example.

```
my $line="SI AL";
my @values=split(/\s+/,$line);chomp(@values);
```

I want to use the element values, like "SI" and "AL", to define hashes,  like %hash_SI_CN_tot_amt, %hash_AL_CN_tot_amt, **where "SI" and "AL" should be a variable**. How can I define hash using variable values? Any further suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further suggestion: [don't do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549685/how-can-i-use-a-variable-as-a-variable-name-in-perl).

Use a multi-dimensional hash instead.

```
@values = ("SI","AL");
...
$hash_CN_tot_amt{"SI"}{$key} = $value;
$hash_CN_tot_amt{$values[1]}{$key2} = $value2;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Every helpful!